# Using a single BroadcastReceiver for a scheduled location update check/compare

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, broadcastreceiver, android-location

As someone from iOS background, I need some help with this.

I have scheduled a task using `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReceiver`.

In the `onReceive` method, I want to calculate the distance between a predefined `LatLng` and the user's current location. But the thing is, the GPS takes time to find a fix. How do I wait until it does?

My guess is using this inside the location fetching class...

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, pendingIntent);
```

Then inside `onReceive`, I check the intent parameter's action and check the distance accordingly.

Please correct me wherever I'm mistaken. :)